# iPhone: supported algorithm for Encryption /decryption

Tags: iphone, algorithm, encryption

i am new to iPhone.
i want to know which Encryption /decryption algorithm is supported by iPhone ?
please suggest or provide me some helpful link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find supported standard encryption algorithms in `CommonCryptor.h` header:

```
enum {
    kCCAlgorithmAES128 = 0,
    kCCAlgorithmDES,        
    kCCAlgorithm3DES,       
    kCCAlgorithmCAST,       
    kCCAlgorithmRC4,
    kCCAlgorithmRC2     
};
```

Comment: can you describe or provide some helpful link which explain the which algorithm is best or compare the algorithm for different condition?